# Performing Math operations on decimal datatype in C#?

Tags: c#, math, types, double, decimal

I was wondering if the above was at all possible.  For example:

```
Math.Sqrt(myVariableHere);
```

When looking at the overload, it requires a double parameter, so I'm not sure if there is another way to replicate this with decimal datatypes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In most cases involving a `decimal` (currency etc), it isn't *useful* to take a root; and the root won't have anything like the expected precision that you might expect a `decimal` to have. You can of course force it by casting (assuming we aren't dealing with extreme ends of the `decimal` range):

```
decimal root = (decimal)Math.Sqrt((double)myVariableHere);
```

which forces you to at least acknowledge the inherent rounding issues.

Comment: Well, I'm making an app calculates golden ratio, which will eventually go to decimal range. Won't work in my scenario.

Answer (score 64):

There are several ways to calculate the square root from a number. One of them was proposed by Isaac Newton. I'll only write one of the simplest implementations of this method. I use it to improve the accuracy of double's square root.

```
// x - a number, from which we need to calculate the square root
// epsilon - an accuracy of calculation of the root from our number.
// The result of the calculations will differ from an actual value
// of the root on less than epslion.
public static decimal Sqrt(decimal x, decimal epsilon = 0.0M)
{
    if (x < 0) throw new OverflowException("Cannot calculate square root from a negative number");

    decimal current = (decimal)Math.Sqrt((double)x), previous;
    do
    {
        previous = current;
        if (previous == 0.0M) return 0;
        current = (previous + x / previous) / 2;
    }
    while (Math.Abs(previous - current) > epsilon);
    return current;
}
```

About speed: in the worst case (epsilon = 0 and number is decimal.MaxValue) the loop repeats less than a three times.

If you want to know more, read [this (*Hacker's Delight* by Henry S. Warren, Jr.)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201914654)

Answer (score 7):

I just came across this question, and I'd suggest a different algorithm than the one SLenik proposed.  This is based on the [Babylonian Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Babylonian_method).

```
public static decimal Sqrt(decimal x, decimal? guess = null)
{
    var ourGuess = guess.GetValueOrDefault(x / 2m);
    var result = x / ourGuess;
    var average = (ourGuess + result) / 2m;

    if (average == ourGuess) // This checks for the maximum precision possible with a decimal.
        return average;
    else
        return Sqrt(x, average);
}
```

It doesn't require using the existing `Sqrt` function, and thus avoids converting to `double` and back, with the accompanying loss of precision.

Comment: Bobson, you proposed another possible solution, but there is no flaw in SLenik's solution because he only uses double Sqrt(double) as a starting point - like a seed. Then, in the loop, he uses the full precision decimal `x` to adjust the resulting value of Sqrt.

Comment: @farfareast - It's a valid point, and under most circumstances the precision issue won't matter. but if you have a very precise decimal in the first place, you will lose a portion of it, which could lead to a slightly-off result.   I also find it philosophically objectionable to calculate the square root by using the square root, although that certainly wouldn't stop me from coding that if I actually needed it and there was a performance reason to do so.

Comment: Also, in my initial testing (and post), my algorithm appeared to be something like 100x faster, but upon further testing, I discovered that the order in which I did the tests affected the results, so I removed that part.  It's still a valid algorithm, and I think it's slightly faster, but it's only a minor difference.  The built-in `double` version of `Sqrt` is still significantly faster than either.

Comment: No wonder double sqrt is faster. Look at this quote from this [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_assembly_language): `Floating point instructions
x86 assembly language includes instructions for a stack-based floating point unit. They include addition, subtraction, negation, multiplication, division, remainder, square roots, integer truncation, fraction truncation, and scale by power of two.` In particular there is FSQRT instruction in the Intel machine code instruction set. :-) See also: [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_instruction_listings)

Comment: I think this is a really awesome solution.  Thanks.

Comment: A benchmark using [BenchmarkDotNet](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet) on my machine showed this solution to be slower than SLenik's, which had a mean time of 250 ns, while this solution had a mean time of 1400 ns. Just for reference, Math.Sqrt had a mean time of 1 ns.

Answer (score -3):

Simple: Cast your `decimal` to a `double` and call the function, get the result and cast that back to a `decimal`. That will probably be faster than any `sqrt` function you could make on your own, and save a lot of effort.

Answer (score -4):

```
Math.Sqrt((double)myVariableHere);
```

Will give you back a double that's the square root of your `decimal` `myVariableHere`.